# Date formatting in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have found many Date functions for Cloud BigQuery and I have a specific case and none of those available functions seem to work.
My data would have a date column in 'MMddyy' format and I would like to convert it into 'yyyy-MM-dd' format. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possibility:

```
#standardSQL
WITH data AS(
  SELECT '072817' as dt UNION ALL
  select NULL UNION ALL
  SELECT ''
)

SELECT IF(dt != '', FORMAT_DATE("%Y-%m-%d", PARSE_DATE("%m%d%y", dt)), dt) FROM data
```

Comment: One more question, what if we get any blank value as input to this date formatting function. My dataset contains some of the blank values for 'date' field which fails the query. I don't want my query to fail. What I want my query to do is if there is a valid value convert it to my desired format otherwise leave the blank the way it is.

Comment: @BalajeeVenkatesh I updated my question, let me know if it works for you.